# C# connection between SqlDataAdapter and Fill

Tags: c#

I needed to write a program that would select from a database with a table named PushTb2, 2 columns named Message and Date.

This is some of the code - I do not know if it contains enough information though.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Message FROM PushTb2 WHERE Date = 'DateNow'", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][0]);
```

How do I establish the connection and how do I make the program work?

Comment: What is happening when you execute this snippet?

Comment: Seeing your connection string may help. Also specifying the database system.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your SQL statement is wrong and what you really want is `"SELECT Date,Message FROM PushTb2 WHERE Date >= getdate()-1"` other than that, everything looks ok...

ps: your connection string could be wrong, but that would throw an exception, and not only return and empty result...

Comment: Testing with getdate() will probably not give you any results either, as that checks for messages in the last few milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you, I've done something similar:

```
var datenow = DateTime.Now.ToString();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Message, Date FROM PushTb2 WHERE Date = '" +datenow+ "'", con);
```

I think every other line of code looks OK, But make sure your connection string is valid.